# Why I am getting age[i] as undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here I am going to describe my problem that why I am getting `age[i]=a` as undefined when I am going to console it

[image]

```js
const birthYear = [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]

function calc(Year) {
  age = 2022 - Year;
  return age

}
var age = []
age[0] = 123;
console.log(age[0])

for (i = 0; i <= birthYear.length - 1; i++) {
  var a = calc(birthYear[i])

  /* if you want to return the value of any function you have to  address 
     it the help of any agruement otherwise it will show you a function body
   */
  age[i] = a
  // console.log
  console.log(age[i])
}

// console.log(age[])
```

Comment: Take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/979052), as in it's current state your question is not easy to read.

Comment: When do you get the problem?

Comment: No images of code please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you return "age" with calc and also called your array "age".
Hence the array gets replaced everytime and you're getting "undefined".

Try this :

```
const birthYear=[1996,1997,1998,1999]

function calc(Year) {
    age=2022-Year;
    return age
}

var ageArr = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < birthYear.length ; i++){
    ageArr[i] = calc(birthYear[i])
    console.log(ageArr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**why I am getting age[i] as undefined?**

you have used var keyword to declare age array,now the age become global variable,so when you make a call to calC function it converts array to number
  `age=2022-Year;` after executing this statement . thats the reason age[i] is undefined .
now whats the correct way to do this,just declare ageCount inside calc function and return it,like this

```
 const birthYear=[1996,1997,1998,1999]
 function calc(Year) 
 {
   //instead of using 2022, you fetch current year from date object
   let ageCount=2022-Year;
   return ageCateCount
}
var age=[]
age[0]=123;
console.log(age[0])

for(i=0;i<=birthYear.length-1;i++){
   age[i]=calc(birthYear[i]);
// console.log

         console.log(age[i])
}
```

```js
const birthYear = [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]

function calc(Year) {
  let ageCount = new Date().getFullYear() - Year;
  return ageCount

}
var age = []
age[0] = 123;
console.log(age[0])

for (i = 0; i <= birthYear.length - 1; i++) {
  var a = calc(birthYear[i])

  /* if you want to return the value of any function you have to  address 
     it the help of any agruement otherwise it will show you a function body
   */
  age[i] = a
  // console.log
  console.log(age[i])
}
```

hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly, You want to find the difference from year 2022 to the years in the `birthYear` array. If Yes, You can simply achieve this with a single line of code instead of making it complex.

Demo **:**

```js
const birthYear = [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999];

const age = birthYear.map(year => 2022 - year);

console.log(age);
```